# Why does select multiple work correctly in Svelte REPL, but not in local Sveltekit application

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

The following code works as expected in the [Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/184102411cde4de3b6875b86adbe1ee0?version=3.58.0)

```
<script>
    let selected = [1,2];
    let availableValues = [
        { id: 1, name: 'one' },
        { id: 2, name: 'two' },
        { id: 3, name: 'three' },
        { id: 4, name: 'four' },
        { id: 5, name: 'five' }
    ];
</script>
<form>
    <select multiple bind:value={selected}>
    {#each availableValues as value}
        <option value={value.id}>{value.name}</option>
    {/each}
    </select>
</form>
<div>
    Items selected: {selected}
</div>
```

However, using the same code within a page in a local Sveltekit app does not work. Single clicking an option selects the option correctly, however, using ctrl-click to select multiple options works only occasionally - if at all.

What might be different between the REPL and the local app that would cause this and what could I do to get it working in the app?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Only thing you could add is `(value.id)` after `as value`. https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks 

Other than that, I could only imagine a browser extension or event handler from different parts of your application interfering. Double-check that your small example works in isolation without any other code locally.

Comment: @TobiObeck Thanks for the suggestion - seems to be a chrome extension -Link Klipper that is interfering. No longer in the web store so now deleted.